# What is filesystem and efi doing in file explorer panel?

Tags: mount, caja

my file explorer (caja on Ubuntu Mate 18.04) is suddenly showing 2 mounted devices `filesystem` and `efi`. My hard drive is not mounting now. 
What might be the problem?

[Screenshot. Please look in the left pane for external mounted devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlzzR.png)

Answer (score 0):

There only possibility I can think of is that a recent update caused the appearance of drives/partitions on your pc. On my pc `filesystem` is merely a shortcut to your root folder.`efi` means [Extensible Firmware Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) system partition or ESP is a partition on a data storage device (usually a hard disk drive or solid-state drive) that is used by computers adhering to the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI).